# Pdf.js not rendering Urdu nastaleeq font properly

Tags: pdf.js, urdu

I'm trying to render a pdf file on my site, but the Urdu script (Jameel Noori Nastaleeq font) isn't rendered correctly. As you can see, pdf.js renders it wrong. Does anyone know what could be the problem? The pdf is created using LaTex. [Here is a link to a folder containing two screenshots and the original pdf file.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9loCyDBc62ZWmpSSHF6anVLZE0&usp=sharing) pdf_bad is rendered in pdf.js, pdf_good is rendered in Adobe Reader.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is actually a bug in pdf.js. I downloaded the beta version (1.1.1), and it actually worked there. It still renders some text wrong, but I think it is being fixed. Thanks to anyone who tried to find an answer for this question.